# Is it bad if I do not end the session when using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have written some code for a camera app like snapchat, in it the user holds a button to take a video. To try and speed up the process of going from one view to another we have gotten rid of the bellow function:

```
    func stopSession() {

    //if it is running then stop running
    if captureSession.isRunning {
        videoQueue().async {
            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

}
```

Instead of calling this I only use:

```
    func stopRecording() {

    if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
        movieOutput.stopRecording()
    }
}
```

This causes makes it so when the user lets go of the button it instantly changes to the preview. I have not found any errors occurring due to this. So I was wondering... Is there any problem in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't skip stopping the session

`stopRunning()`

> This method is used to stop the flow of data from the inputs to the outputs connected to the AVCaptureSession instance that is the receiver. This method is synchronous and blocks until the receiver has completely stopped running.

despite it will speed your process , the flow will continue which will drain the resources of the user , `stopRecording` only stops writing to the output file that you set here

```
startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Don't do this stopRunning(), does this mean , dont "do" this method or do u mean dont do what teh question says I am doing?

Comment: So you are saying that because we do not stop the session, even though we may have stoped running, we will still be using user resources? If so would it then make sense to only stop the session when teh user leaves the VC entierly or exits the app, and it goes into teh background?

Comment: consider handed frames from camera & michrophone will fly without usage is that a good way , yes you have to stop any memory consuming action when going to background to stay as far as possible running in background its a very useful action when you say you want to play a sound in background mode , BTW finally for every stop you will get a new output file , you may merge them  to get the complete recorded video